# How can I output ALL strings from a lang file?

Tags: plugin-development, localization

I need to output a JSON object containing all of the key/value pairs in either `/translations/{myLocale}.php` or `/craft/plugins/myplugin/translations/{myLocale}.php`.

I can't see any way of doing that?

I can see that I can call `craft()->getComponent('messages')` but that will retrieve all of Craft's internal translations - I only want the messages I have defined in one of the files above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the translations file into your controller:

```
$translationsFile = craft()->path->getPluginsPath().'myplugin/translations/de.php';
$translationsArray = include $translationsFile;

$this->returnJson(array_keys($translationsArray));
```